# "undefined reference" on including *.h *.cpp file to node package

Tags: ros, c++, include, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to build my first project in ROS and so far I am amazed. But since yesterday I got stuck on a problem with including a separate *.h and *.cpp file.
I copied the files in a subdirectory in /src called ThirdParty/brisk and added the include paths to the CMakeLists.txt as you can see below (to #include files with <> instead ot ""). I also build an eclipse project and the auto-completition shows me the classes from the included files, but when i try to build it I get the error "undefined reference" as you can see below! Somehow the compiler does not get the *.cpp file (aka brisk.cpp), but I got no idea what I did wrong!

Probably just one little link/include/cmd is missing!!!

I have read a lot about this "undefined reference" error and to mention that: the file brisk.h and brisk.cpp work well in a "not-ROS" project. So the common mistake of forgetting BriskFeatureDetector::BriskFeatureDetector(...) isn't the problem here!

I hope you cam help!!

thx!

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

include_directories(/home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ThirdParty/brisk)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()

rosbuild_add_executable(ImgProcEngineNode src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.cpp)
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(ImgProcEngineNode "-c -fmessage-length=0 
-march=native -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -I/home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ThirdParty/brisk 
-I/home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ThirdParty/brisk/agast")
```

manifest.xml

```
<package>
  <description brief="topological_map_v1">
    topological_map_v1
  </description>
  <author>me</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/topological_map_v1</url>

  <depend package="opencv2"/>
  <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>

  <export>
     <cpp cflags="-msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -I/ThirdParty/brisk -I/ThirdParty/brisk/agast"/>
     <intel_cpp cflags="-msse2 -msse3 -mssse3"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

rosImgProcEngine.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "topological_map_v1/rosImageIn.h"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/ml.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/operations.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <brisk.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  Ptr<FeatureDetector> _detector = new BriskFeatureDetector(90,4);
  Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> _extractor = new BriskDescriptorExtractor(false);

...
}
```

Console Output after "make"

```
...
CMakeFiles/ImgProcEngineNode.dir/src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.o: In function `main':
/home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.cpp:31: undefined reference to `cv::BriskFeatureDetector::BriskFeatureDetector(int, int)'
/home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.cpp:32: undefined reference to `cv::BriskDescriptorExtractor::BriskDescriptorExtractor(bool, bool, float)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/ImgProcEngineNode] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ImgProcEngineNode.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44811/%22undefined-reference%22-on-including-*.h-*.cpp-file-to-node-package/) by [MiseryInDevice](https://answers.ros.org/users/3284/miseryindevice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mmmmm... you should indicate rosbuild_add_executable where to find the file where the undefined references are implemented (brisk.cpp)

try to change this line

```
rosbuild_add_executable(ImgProcEngineNode src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.cpp)
```

for this other

```
rosbuild_add_executable(ImgProcEngineNode src/ros_src/rosImgProcEngine.cpp /home/me/topological_map/topological_map_v1/src/ThirdParty/brisk/brisk.cpp)
```

Also, I would avoid using absolute paths on CMakeLists.txt, it will be very messy if you want to compile your project on another machine.

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5